# How to solve the recursive formula $$A(n,k)=A(n-1,k)+A(n,k-1)+A(n-1,k-1)$$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

Is there any known solution for the recursive formula
$$A(n,k)=A(n-1,k)+A(n,k-1)+A(n-1,k-1)$$
for given initial values A(0,0), A(1,0) and A(0,1)?
Does this formula have any geometric or combinatorial known meaning?

Comment: There's an obvious meaning as walks in an $n\times k$ grid from bottom-left to top-right with the allowed steps being up, right, and diagonal up-right.

Comment: This is not enough boundary data to uniquely specify A in the interior if the quadrant $\{ (n,m): n,m \geq 0\}$. Specifying A on the entire boundary of the quadrant would create a well posed problem, however.

Comment: One obvious thing to do is put 1's on boundary $\{(n,m):n,m\geq 0\}$, run the computation, and then feed the diagonal entries A(n,n) into the online encyclopedia of integer sequences. If you do this, you would get this sequence https://oeis.org/A001850. You also get https://oeis.org/A050146 from a slightly different computation.

Comment: If we set all boundary points equal to 1, then my calculations indicate that the determinant of the $n\times n$-matrix $A(i,j)$ will be $2^{n(n-1)/2}$. It looks like this is related to the determinant of Pascal's triangle which is 1 (Timothy Gowers had fun with this determinant https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byjhpzEoXFs ). It therefore seems like when we consider A(i,j) as a matrix, then A(i,j) can be factored as a product of n(n-1)/2 matrices of determinant 2 (or something like that).

Comment: There are many different choices of the set of points (i,j) where A(i,j) is given initial values. There are also different choices of the domain of the set $A$. Do we want the domain of $A$ to be $\mathbb{Z}^2$ or $\mathbb{N}^2$?

Comment: @JosephVanName, it's often more useful to build a table and search for an antidiagonal. E.g. searching for 1,9,25,25,9,1 finds [A008288](https://oeis.org/A008288)

Comment: Let $A_0(n,k)$ be the solution for boundary conditions $A_0(0,0)=1$, $A_0(n,0)=A_0(0,k)=0$ for $n,k>0$. Then the general solution is $A(n,k)=A(0,0)A_0(n,k)+\sum_{i>0}A(i,0)A_0(n-i,k)+\sum_{j>0}A(0,j)A_0(n,k-j)$.

Comment: The  generating function $F(x,y)=\sum_{k,n\geq 0} A(n,k)x^n y^k$ is rational  and  has the form $$ F(x,y)=\frac{a+bx+cy}{1+x+y-xy} $$. The coefficients $a,b,c,d$ can be  described explicitly in terms of  $A(0,0), A(0,1), A(1,0)$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu How does your comment square with Terry Tao’s comment above?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I was obviously wrong.  The numerator should be  $a+b(x)+c(y)$, $b,c$ power series.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu All right. Though now I wonder about the denominator as well: shouldn’t it rather be $1-x-y-xy$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek  Yes.